# Required Fields when creating a page

Tags: publishing-page

I have created a content type that has site column which will be required. The content type is based on the article content type.

When I create the page, I would like the form used to display the page's properties before going to the layout where the content is created to force the use to fill in the required site column with information.

I know this can be done with a edit mode panel, but eventually there will be several required site columns that will not be displayed on the page. I was hoping that there must be a way to take users to the EditForm.aspx (Edit Page Properties screen) before going to the actual page.

Thanks ...

Mike